# Reaching an object from different class

Tags: java, oop

[image: There are codes about Account class.]

I created several instance variables, constructors, getters, setters and methods in Account Class. Now I want to add a Customer class with two instance variables called name and account, in order to link the customer with the account object that I've created. So, my teacher told me that I can write it in this way.

[image: There are codes about Customer class.]

But I don't understand the logic behind on writing `Private Account account`. Does `Account` come from Account class and do I have to write`account` in order to link with the other account objects that I've created? Furthermore,

[image]

```
this.account.report();
```

Does this line calls the method from the Account class, if so how the program understands that it should call this method from Account class? Thank you for answering.

Comment: I am not sure what is confusing you. "how the program understands that it should call this method from `Account` class". You defined `account` field as `private Account account` so it may hold only *references* (unique object identifier) to objects of `Account` type (BTW it also includes subclass of Account class if there will be any). At `this.account.report()` JVM will use reference held at `this.account` to locate that object in memory, which will allow it to know actual type of that object. This will let JVM information in which type it should search for *body* of `.report()` method.

Comment: BTW don't post text/code as image/link ([more info](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private Account account
```

Your teacher is coding in an object-oriented way.
Whenever you create a new version of Customer, you need to add two parameters to the constructor, `name` and `account`.

Write `Account account` in the customer class for the purpose of reuse in the Customer class itself.

`this.account.report();` calls the method from the Account class. program understands that it should call this method from Account class because `this.account` is a instance of Account class and it contain all method, property and fields of Account class